# I m writitng shell script where i m deleting index which older than 10 days and also excluding some index which not deleted

Tags: bash, shell, elasticsearch, kibana

```
#!/bin/bash

older_days_10=$(date -d '-10 day' '+%Y-%d-%m')
echo $older_days_10

deleteIndex(){

        if [ $(curl -X DELETE http:localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=creation.date.string) -le  $(older_days_10)  ]  && [ $(curl -X DELETE http:localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=creation.date.string) eq $(older_days_10)  ]
        then
curl -X DELETE http:localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=creation.date.string,index |grep -wv -e .kibana-* -e .siem-*


else
        echo "There no index which is older than 10 days"
fi

}

deleteIndex
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include an actual question in your question.

Comment: BTW, `$(older_days_10)` seems wrong. Did you mean `${older_days_10}`?

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend.

Comment: In `[ a -le b ]` `a` and `b` must be integers. Your `older_days_10` is not an integer, it is something like `YYYY-dd-mm`. This will cause syntax errors. Moreover, using a year-day-month format is not a very good idea to compare dates. Prefer year-month-day. It should be `-eq`, not `eq`. What is the point in testing for lower or equal **AND** equal? Isn't this equivalent to just equal?

Comment: Why do you use the `DELETE` method to fetch the date from the server? Why do you call it multiple times instead of storing its result?

Comment: you are checking `if [ a -le b ] && [ a -eq b ]` (if your syntax was right), whicharen't both useful. Paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix what it tells you until it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use [ILM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) here, it's built to handle this and you don't need to be custom writing scripts